# Android Studio 3.4 stuck on indexing project

Tags: android-studio

Few days ago, I have update android studio 3.4. 
Now, when I open any project or build new project it's stuck on indexing.

I have try many solution like "Invalid catch and restart", remove ".android", remove ".gradle" and remove ".AndroidStudio3.4" folder but still I have facing this issue in android studio 3.4.

When I forcefully close android studio from windows task manager then after android studio not starting again until restart system and task manager in showing android studio running.

How can I solved this issue?

Comment: Please uninsall and install again, u r problem will be resolved. Thank u

Comment: Is this problem relates to only specific project?

Comment: do you find an error in the logcat window?

Comment: @RahulKhurana no, every project in problem occur.

Comment: @RahulChokshi No, not found any error in logcat window.

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing android studio again

Comment: try to move to another folder

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling. No need to uninstall, you just need to follow the steps in the setup to remove that version. If your computer tells you that there are files with the same name then simply overwrite.